# Is this solvable for $d$? $r = \frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin(n\pi d)}{\sin(\pi d)}$

Tags: trigonometry

Is this solvable for $d$?

$r = \frac{1}{n}\frac{\sin(n\pi d)}{\sin(\pi d)}$

$n$ is an integer, use $n = 2$ if that makes it significantly easier.

Inspired by this EE question:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/669376/what-is-the-formula-for-measuring-squarewave-duty-cycle-from-a-spectrum/669419#669419

(no need to watch the video, look at the answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=2$, then using $\sin2u=2\sin u\cos u$ we get $r=\cos\pi d$, whence $d=(1/\pi)\arccos r$.

Comment: Of course this only gives real $d$ if $r\lt 1$ If $r=1$ we would need to cancel zeros of $\sin(\pi d)$.

Comment: Yes, 0 < *r < 1